# How do you use sum () with list items?

Tags: python, text-files

I am trying to create a program which prints the mean of certain values in a file. When I run my code using the file 'cropdata.txt', which contains this:

```
Lettuce 1 2 3 
Tomato 6 5 1
```

I get the following error:

```
    line_mean = (sum(line_parts[1:])/len(line_parts))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

I am not really sure why this is as I thought that I had converted the selected elements to integers.

My code:

```
file = ('cropdata.txt')
with open(file, 'r') as file_numsort_1:
    for line in file_numsort_1:
        line = (line.rstrip(" \n"))
        line_parts = line.split(' ')
        for num in line_parts[1:]:
            num=int(num)
        line_mean = (sum(line_parts[1:])/len(line_parts))
        print(line_mean)
```

Comment: `sum(map(int, line_parts[1:]))`, and you'd want to divide by `len(line_parts) - 1`. `num = int(num)` only rebinds `num`, not the value still in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Your code

```
for num in line_parts[1:]:
    num=int(num)
```

isn't really doing anything, as the variable `num` gets overwritten each iteration of the loop.  Therefore, none of the data is converted from `str` to `int` type which is the cause of your error.  What you want to do is create a list of numbers as such:

```
file = ('cropdata.txt')
with open(file, 'r') as file_numsort_1:
    for line in file_numsort_1:
        line = (line.rstrip(" \n"))
        line_parts = line.split(' ')

        num_list = []
        for num in line_parts[1:]:
            num_list.append(int(num))

        line_mean = sum(num_list)/float(len(num_list))
```

A few other things to note:

- Using `line.split(' ')` is a little superfluous as `line.split()` will automatically split whitespace delimiters.  It also counts consecutive spaces as one delimeter
- No argument is needed in `line = line.rstrip()` and you certainly don't need the enclosing parenthesis
- I've added a `float()` function to your `line_mean` calculation.  In Python 2, operations on two integers stay as an integer (so 5/3 = 1, not 1.66).  <s>I believe Python 3 has similar behavior but this extra function doesn't hurt if not</s> (Thanks for the clarification Bharel), this float function is not needed in Python 3

Comment: Python 3 does not have a similar behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Upon converting like this `num=int(num)`, you didn't save the conversion back in the list.
Try converting like so:

```
line_parts = [int(x) for x in line_parts[1:]]
```

and then sum like so:

```
line_mean = (sum(line_parts)/len(line_parts))
```

Alternatively you may use the [statistics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean) module instead of summing yourself.

---

An optimized version:

```
import statistics

file = ('cropdata.txt')
with open(file, 'r') as file_numsort_1:
    for line in file_numsort_1:
        # Strip, split, and convert to int
        line_ints = map(int, line.rstrip().split()[1:])

        # Print the mean
        print(statistics.mean(line_ints))
```

Comment: This would drop `line_parts[0]` altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not with `sum` but the list of 'numbers', this should solve your problem:

```
line_parts = line.split(' ')
list_of_nums = [int(item) for item in line_parts[1:]]
line_mean = (sum(list_of_nums)/len(C))
print(line_mean)
```